# NSArray with UI objects (Performance)

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiwebview, nsarray

I have a `NSArray` (actually is a mutable array) with a `UIWebView` object in each index. I use this array to populate cell in a `UITableView`. I use a `for` loop to initialize each object in the array as following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.events count]; i++) {

    [self.uiWebViewArray addObject:[[UIWebView alloc] init]];
    [[self.uiWebViewArray objectAtIndex:i] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [[self.uiWebViewArray objectAtIndex:i] loadHTMLString:HTMLContent baseURL:nil];   
}
```

At this point I am not populating the `UITableViewCells` yet.

Although it works, I think that it a terrible approach. Performance goes down when I increase the number of cell. At some point, it is possible to the user note the latency.

I also tried to populate each cell directly with a `UIWebView` but it is basically the same thing.

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve the problem of populate `UITableViewCell` with `UIWebView` objects in a efficient way?

A really appreciate any help.

Comment: Where do you put this cycle to? In which method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a custom cell with a Web View inside it will be the better. Although whole concept of Web View inside a table view is weird.

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you would need to do something like:

[cell.webView loadHTMLString:HTMLContent baseURL:nil];

The main advantage of Table View is that the number of actual UITableViewCell instances created in memory are far less than total number of logical cells/rows. Actually, in usual cases Table View only creates cells needed to fill the frame, plus few extra.

So using custom table view cell with Web View inside is way better approach memory wise, but as I said whole idea is a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you! I ends up creating a custom `UITableViewCell` with two `UILabel` and one `UITextView`. Therefore I could completely remove the `UIWebView` from the cell. In fact the performance is much better now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the array, is the webview that is really slow and memory hugry.
If you want to display HTML text with basic CSS and you are deploying >= iOS7, you should use `NSAttributeString` and that method:

```
NSDictionary *importParams = @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding) };
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *stringData = [HTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData options:importParams documentAttributes:NULL error:&error];
```

Or you can use third party libraries [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact the webview is really slow. I replaced it by a custom tableviewcell.  Thanks anyway...